# Calculate the tangent of an angle for multiple angles in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    DATE        TIME            A       B
0   2016-01-01  00:00:00.000    443.30  469.80
1   2016-01-01  00:01:00.000    145.80  470.00
2   2016-01-01  00:03:00.000    452.20  471.00
3   2016-01-01  00:04:00.000    174.20  461.30
4   2016-01-01  00:05:00.000    345.30  471.90
```

I'm basically just trying to calculate the tangent of angles (A/B) for all  rows of the dataframe.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m

df['I']=np.(m.degrees(m.atan(df['A']/df['B'])))
```

The error produced:

```
File "<ipython-input-70-0abce3902356>", line 3
df['I']=np.(m.degrees(m.atan(df['A']/df['B'])))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Taking the () out produces another error:

```
df['I']=np.m.degrees(m.atan(df['A']/df['B']))

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-7cfc6387d664> in <module>()
       1 
       2 
 ----> 3 df['I']=np.m.degrees(m.atan(df['A']/df['B']))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'm'
```

I understand what the errors are telling me, I just don't really know how to go about performing the calculation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve with `np.(`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the numpy functions [`np.degrees`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.degrees.html) and [`np.arctan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html). The `math` module functions aren't designed to work on vectors.

```
df['I'] = np.degrees(np.arctan(df['A']/df['B']))
df
         DATE          TIME      A      B          I
0  2016-01-01  00:00:00.000  443.3  469.8  43.337628
1  2016-01-01  00:01:00.000  145.8  470.0  17.234557
2  2016-01-01  00:03:00.000  452.2  471.0  43.833393
3  2016-01-01  00:04:00.000  174.2  461.3  20.687963
4  2016-01-01  00:05:00.000  345.3  471.9  36.193786
```

By the way, `np` – alias for `numpy` and `m` – alias for `math` (builtin). Not sure why you're trying to use them the way you are.

Comment: Cheers for that! I wasn't aware of those numpy functions, still learning and learning...